# Threads/Multiple TCP clients and usermanagement

Tags: android, tcp, server

https://github.com/CatalinPrata/funcodetuts/tree/master/JavaTCPServer/src/ro/kazy/tcp

How do i use threads/multiple clients by using putty (or an android client) to connect to the server. How to return which user is connected?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (running) {
System.out.println(getuser(socket));
}
```

something like this only users are added to a UserManager Thread & class(..)  and the class has a lot of objects + interface. yes.. what is a interface? & yes.. i wil find out about using a different usermanager.